# Table "table" must be qualified with a dataset in CTE table

Tags: common-table-expression

why do i get this error ( Table "table" must be qualified with a dataset (e.g. dataset.table) when calling table in CTE

Answer (score 0):

You can add dataset name before table name. Just like:

```
select * from dataset_name.table_name
```

Answer (score -2):

Did you run the query only select certain rows?

You can try to run all the rows or make sure the query that you block when running, doesn't connect with another query.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i forgot to block the query from the "With blabla as" in CTE. thank you it works